# How to make COM Add-in inactive?

Tags: vba, excel, comaddin

I have a COM Add-in, which I want to make inactive with VBA Code (or maybe with another Excel Add-in '.xla').

This is my company's internal COM Add-in.

Working of this COM Add-in: While closing a workbook, a form is generated. This form asks which type of workbook (like private, confidential).

This COM Add-in can be made inactive without VBA by the following method:

1. Excel>Options>Add-Ins
2. Click On 'Manage - COM Addins' and 'Go'.
3. Deselect that Add-IN from Add-in manager & Click 'Ok'.

However, after opening a new workbook the add-in starts working again.

The solution to this issue is to create VBA code (/Excel Add-in) with workbook_open event to disconnect the COM add-in:

```
Application.COMAddIns("AddinName").Connect = False
```

But getting below error:
This add-in is installed for all users on this computer and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator.

If one can make this COM Add-in inactive manually then why is it not allowed with VBA code?